# No such module Common Crypto

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header, commoncrypto, objc-bridging-header

I am working with swift 3.2. I have made a bridging header file which has the following:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

In my projects build setting I am pointing to my bridging header file but i am still getting the error `'No such module CommonCrypto'` in my classes where I am using import CommonCrypto

*update*:
header file:

```
#ifndef ProjectName_Bridging_Header_h
#define ProjectName_Bridging_Header_h

#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

#endif
```

Comment: can you show your entire bridging header, I imported common crypto the exact same way you did and mine is working fine

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/03/using-commoncrypto-in-swift/)?

Comment: you don't need to do `import CommonCrypto` if you already have it in your header file. You can just use it straight

Comment: @TNguyen if I remove import CommonCrypto then I get warnings saying 'use of unresolved identifier CommonCrypto'

Comment: Previoulsy I had commonCrypto in a framework and had used an aggregate. With that I needed to import CommonCrypto and use it like CommonCrypto.kCCOptionPKCS7Padding for example. I removed all my 'CommonCrypto.' references from my swift file and it worked- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the workaround to make Xcode be able to find `CommonCrypto` via Swift module as stated [here](https://gist.github.com/commscheck/76d23e4af3c4e3fbec7c31ce57795835#file-hmac-swift-L9-L24) by Mihael Isaev.

I used such approach in my project (Xcode 9.3, Swift 4). I summarize steps as follows.

1. Create a new directory namely `CommonCrypto` at the root of your project (or for me I created it at the same level of `AppDelegate.swift` file)
2. Create a file name `module.map` inside that directory (done outside Xcode) with following content

   ```
   module CommonCrypto [system] {
      header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"
      export *
   }
   ```

   If you install Xcode elsewhere, you can manually find location of such `.app` yourself then append it with `/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h` or you can execute `xcode-select -p` to get the path of Xcode then append it with `/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h`
3. Go to `Build Settings` in Xcode then search for `swift compiler - search paths`.
4. Enter `$(PROJECT_DIR)/<project name>/CommonCrypto` into its `Import Paths` in which `<project name>` is your project name.
5. Now you will be able to build the project, and Xcode would find such module.

**Note**: No need to add such `CommonCrypto` directory which hosts `module.map` file into Xcode via `Add Files to ...`. It only used in compilation step thus no problem there.

Comment: are you using rave framework ? inside commoncrypto module what has to be the path in my case  `.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h` where the commoncrypto is should i replace this ?